# How can I force React to re-render all components on a page that come from array.map?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a parent component (Game) that renders children (Card) from an array. I also have a Menu component that does a callback to Game to change its state. When I change levels (button click from Menu), I want all current cards to fade out, then fade in with the new ones, so they mimic the fade-in CSS applied to newly rendered Cards. I've tried forceUpdate in a couple places, and passing dummy props to check for a change. Basicly, I want all cards currently on the page to re-render while the page renders new ones when needed.

Here is a snippet from Game:

```
{this._gameArray.map( (item, i) => {
  let dummyProp = Math.random();
  return <Card key={i}
           ...
           dummyProp={dummyProp}/>
})}
```

And a snippet from Card:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  ...
  if (nextProps.dummyProp !== this.props.dummyProps) {
    this.forceUpdate();
  }
}
```

I'm using componentWillReceiveProps for another purpose, and decided to try it for testing the dummyProp change. The new Cards fade in, but the ones before do not do anything.

Comment: Does it help to use `<Card key={item.id} />` or  `<Card key={JSON.stringify(item)} />` instead? Don't use an index as a key.

Comment: I don't see why that would help the situation. When I click any of the menu items (let's say to change the level) the Game re-renders because I setState. When the Game renders, it renders a Card from each item in the _gameArray. Because Game renders again, which then renders Cards, I would expect those Cards to rerender as well, but they are not. I'm not using any id tags to grab any specific Card component. Plus, while not ideal, the console doesn't flag the index-as-key as a problem, so I'm not worried about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React has some algorithms to define which components should be re-rendered, in your case React won't re-render the  component because you use indexes as keys and indexes are the same. You need to update `key` between re-renderings.

As the simplest solution you can use the index + some trail in a key, something like this:

```
<Card key={index + '-' + Date.now()} card={card}/>;
```

In this case, the `<Card/>` component will be re-rendered every time when the state of the `<Game/>` component has changed.

```js
class Card extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props)
            }

            render() {
                return (
                    <div class="card">Card {this.props.card.name}</div>
                )
            }
        }

        class Game extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props)

                this.state = {
                    counter: 0,
                    cards: [
                        { name: 'Card1' },
                    ]
                }
            }

            increaseCounter = () => {
                this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 })
            }

            render() {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <h2 onClick={this.increaseCounter}>Click me: {this.state.counter}</h2>
                        <h3>Will be re-rendered</h3>
                            {this.state.cards.map((card, index) => {
                                return <Card key={index + '-' + Date.now()} card={card} />;
                            })}
                        <h3>Won't be re-rendered</h3>
                            {this.state.cards.map((card, index) => {
                                return <Card key={index} card={card} />;
                            })}
                    </div>
                )
            }
        }

        ReactDOM.render(<Game />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.card{
  animation: fade-in-out 3000ms ease-in-out forwards; 
}

  @keyframes fade-in-out {
    0% {
      background-color: transparent;
    }
     50% {
      background-color: red;
    }
     100%{
      background-color: transparent;
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

BUT, for real-life application, I would recommend you to consider the using of some React animation library like [react-transition-group](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/), because if you animate cards only with CSS, there is can be some flashing if re-rendering will happen faster than animation timeout.

Comment: This approach works beautifully! However, now my card-flip animation is not showing when I change the Game settings.

Comment: It's hard to find the reason of the problem without code. Can you post it as a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try a different trick.
If you want all the components to re-render each time a level changes, you can use a boolean, set it to false when you start the change, and set it to true when you finish the change / after some time.
Then add a condition to the rendering of the elements.

```
{shouldRender && this._gameArray.map( (item, i) => {
  let dummyProp = Math.random();
  return <Card key={i}
           ...
           dummyProp={dummyProp}/>
})}
```

when shouldRender is true the cards will be rendered, and when it's false they won't. That way each time it will be true they will all re-rendered and you'll have you effect.

Comment: This works. I actually tried having the boolean but I did not use it the same way. However, I'm going to go with another answer. It works, and is simple to implement.